# Is there any convenient way to develop Spark source code?

Tags: apache-spark

I've already read *[Userful Developer Tools](https://spark.apache.org/developer-tools.html)* provided by Spark. But it does not mention how to develop something that can not be done in local mode.

For example, I'm trying to develop `ExecutorAllocationManager.scala`, this class refers to dynamic Executor allocation. The method I use now is to compile Spark source code locally and deploy it to the cluster(Several machines) for testing, but this is too troublesome, seriously affects the efficiency of development.

Isn’t there a convenient or automated way to develop such functions?

Answer (score 0):

What about continous integration add Jenkins and deploy as per requirments .

- https://devops.com/using-spark-and-jenkins-to-deploy-code-into-hadoop-clusters/